# Nested divs inside a container popup set with % height: adding padding moves the divs outside the popup

Tags: css

*Note:* I looked at this question:
[Can't Prevent Nested Div's from Overflowing when using Percent Sizes and Padding in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703631/cant-prevent-nested-divs-from-overflowing-when-using-percent-sizes-and-padding)
and tried to use `box-sizing: border-box;` but it does not seem to fix the problem.

---

**Question:**

I have a popup container with different stacked scrollable divs, whose heights are set in percentage. 
Everything works well if I don't use `padding`. If I add padding, everything is moved down and the divs are displayed outside the popup window.

How can I use `padding` with heights in percentages?

Here my example code:

```
<div class="cardinfobutton">
  <a href="#popup">click me</a>
</div>


<div id="popup" class="infooverlay">
  <div class="infopopup">
    <div class="content-top">
      <p>This goes at the top</p>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <p>
        Long text, it has to be scrollable
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <p>
         Long text, it has to be scrollable
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-bottom">
      <p>This goes at the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- close infopopup -->
</div> <!-- close infooverlay -->
```

And here the CSS code:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content-top,
.content-bottom {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}
.content-body {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.infooverlay {
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.infooverlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.infopopup {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20 5px 20;
}
```

You can find the example code showing the problem at this codepen:

https://codepen.io/riclab/pen/XePbxR

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you have a set fixed height on the popup, so the content doesnt fit inside it,

you can add style 'overflow:auto' to the .infopopup class to stop the content falling our the box, 
on top of this I would probably remove the max heights from the content containers inside the popup so you dont have too many scroll bars.

n.b. also one of your padding attributes has units missing,
it reads "5px 20 5px 20" when it should say 20px or 20% for example

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with flex. I have also added some min-height to .content-body to show content in minimal height screen.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content-top,
.content-bottom {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content-body {
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.infooverlay {
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.infooverlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.infopopup {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardinfobutton">
  <a href="#popup">click me</a>
</div>


<div id="popup" class="infooverlay">
  <div class="infopopup">
    <div class="content-top">
      <p>This goes at the top</p>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <p>
        Exercitation minim ex sit commodo anim magna in dolore minim occaecat irure eu est pariatur. Ut tempor ex adipisicing lorem cupidatat aliquip consequat. Voluptate ex velit magna id voluptate officia amet, ut consectetur excepteur aute duis aliquip dolore
        ea ipsum labore dolor excepteur do magna veniam, eiusmod deserunt ut velit commodo esse aliqua. Ut amet, nisi sed nulla ullamco i. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt
        anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco
        lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate
        id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi
        exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat
        eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur.
        Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam,
        sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor
        aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="title">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <p>
        Exercitation minim ex sit commodo anim magna in dolore minim occaecat irure eu est pariatur. Ut tempor ex adipisicing lorem cupidatat aliquip consequat. Voluptate ex velit magna id voluptate officia amet, ut consectetur excepteur aute duis aliquip dolore
        ea ipsum labore dolor excepteur do magna veniam, eiusmod deserunt ut velit commodo esse aliqua. Ut amet, nisi sed nulla ullamco i. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt
        anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco
        lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate
        id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi
        exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat
        eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam, sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur.
        Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio. Amet, culpa quis commodo esse sint adipisicing in irure sit non veniam,
        sit magna aute nisi exercitation dolor sunt anim reprehenderit excepteur nulla anim ut aliqua. Qui mollit nulla deserunt in pariatur. Enim ea ut voluptate id ipsum laboris et deserunt ut veniam, nostrud esse ut id sed consequat. Excepteur ut tempor
        aliquip fugiat eiusmod esse sit ullamco lorem exercitatio.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-bottom">
      <p>This goes at the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- close infopopup -->
</div>
<!-- close infooverlay -->
```